# Django's urls file interpretes twice

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I spotted a really weird behavior in my Django project. My `urls.py` just gets interpreted twice for some reason, which is unfortunately causing a lot of trouble. For debugging, I put these two lines

```
import traceback
tracebak.print_stack()
```

into my `urls.py` file. This is the output I get when I do `./manage.py runserver`:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 890, in _bootstrap
    self._bootstrap_inner()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 579, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 572, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/user/project/urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    traceback.print_stack()
```

and the other stack:

```
  File "/home/user/project/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/user/project/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 598, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 583, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 294, in run
    get_resolver().urlconf_module
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 572, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/user/project/urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    traceback.print_stack()
```

Any ideas what might cause this behavior? Might it be for example some import somewhere in my project? I have completely no idea which pieces of code I should include, so if you have an idea, let me know and I will add them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run your Django app using the development server, an auto-reloader process is spawned to detect changes in your code. This process is initialized the same way your main server process does, and this might be the reason your `urls.py` file is being executed twice.

To verify if this is the cause of your problem, you could try to run the development server without the auto-reload option:

```
python manage.py runserver --noreload
```

Comment: Interesting. When I do the `--noreload` flag, the problem really vanishes. However, I have NEVER done this and NEVER had these problems before...

Comment: Normally, there is no problem with the `urls.py` being executed twice. If this crashes your app, you probably placed some code in that file that should't be there? Note that this behaviour only occurs in development and not in production.

Comment: Makes sense. Since I now know this is normal, I will try to find out what is wrong.